# Devops and Central Certificate Store in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, devops

I am in the process of automating our SSL certificate renewal. As part of this I would like to configure our server estate to use a central certificate store.

The store is on an individual server with a file share that is set to be accessible by a webserver group.
I can manually configure the server to use a central certificate store using the IIS GUI ([Manual configuration panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02blI.png)) but I need to do this for over 500 servers.

How do I enable the central certificate store in IIS, set the physical path, pass credentials for both the path and certificate key password in a secure manner, preferably with PowerShell?

Comment: Use the PS OpenSSL cmdlt : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OpenSSL/1.0.0